# How to upload to javascript string, bypassing server?

Tags: javascript, html, upload

Is it possible to upload a file through html to javascript without having to upload it to the server first? If not, is there another way to do this, flash for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the HTML 5 Filereader API:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/